# Heroku django "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/static'"

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am new to django and heroku. This is the error I'm getting when I deployed my git repository to heroku. Please suggest the changes that I need to change. Thank you in advance

(website) C:\Users\website\src>heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
--noinput
Running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` attached to terminal... up, run.1690

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__
.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__
.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py"
, line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py"
, line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py"
, line 533, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle_noargs
collected = self.collect()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 111, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 27, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
line 270, in listdir
for entry in os.listdir(path):
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/static'
```

settings.py

```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  # Template location

 TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates" ),

    )


if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static",  "static-only" )
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media" )
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static" ),

   )
```

Comment: You should post the part of settings.py talking about STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, or STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 2):

If you have declared your 'STATICFILES_DIRS' variable as below,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

ensure:

1. a static folder (the folder must be named as you specified in the 'STATICFILES_DIRS' variable) exists.
2. it contains a file. You can name a dummy file as '.any' if you've got no file yet.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems that the error comes from the STATICFILES_DIRS var points to a directory that does not exist:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static" )
```

Go to your Django project directory, find the static repository, and note the absolute location.
Then, edit the STATICFILES_DIRS variable in settings.py sothat it points to this location.

For me (that does not imply it should be the same for you), it looks like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../myapp/static'),)
```

Comment: Error changed to this:

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/myapp/static'`





This is the error when I'm trying to push git to heroku  

`Preparing static assets
 Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
 $ heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Comment: But I didn't tell you to write "myapp/static", it was just an example of what I did but I suppose your app is not called "myapp"!!! You have to find what to write, finding the right location.

Comment: My app name is "myapp"